# Acidity of amides

Tags: organic-chemistry

Structure (b) and (c) has two NH groups . So will they lose hydrogen ions from both the N atoms or just from one of the N atoms? Which is the strongest acid? Please explain. [image]

Comment: You need to make some effort to answer this before we will offer advice

Comment: Obviously Pthalimide

Comment: How? Could u please explain. I mean fine, it has got 2 strongly EWGs attached to it. So it will be highly acidic. But will not b) and c) lose 2 H ions in the same time?